# Mailkit MimeKit.MimeMessage error: Unknown initialization parameter: System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailkit

I want to forward an email after add some comment to that. original email saved as eml file so first i load that file and then add my comment to body or attach some new files and then resend email to new email address.

```
var mail = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("sample.eml"));
var orgMessage = new MimeKit.MimeMessage(file);

var builder = new MimeKit.BodyBuilder();
builder.TextBody = "user comment";
builder.Attachments.Add(new MimeKit.MessagePart { Message = orgMessage });
mail.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

First of all in line 3 i get this error:
Unknown initialization parameter: System.Byte[]

Second I read this great answer [Forward email using MailKit (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414995/forward-email-using-mailkit-c) and what is resent parameters for? if i set them my comment on forwarded email not set? and that email resent clearly without any change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unknown initialization parameter: System.Byte[]

This means that there is no `MimeMessage` constructor that takes a `byte[]` parameter.

In other words, you can't do this:

```
var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("sample.eml"));
var orgMessage = new MimeKit.MimeMessage(file);
```

The correct way to load a message from a file is to do this:

```
var orgMessage = MimeMessage.Load ("sample.eml");
```

> Second I read this great answer Forward email using MailKit (C#) and what is resent parameters for? if i set them my comment on forwarded email not set? and that email resent clearly without any change?

The `MimeMessage.Resent*` properties are used only when forwarding a message without attaching it to a new message.

You need to pick only 1 of the 3 solutions in the answer of mine that you linked to.

If you are going to attach the original message (like you are doing), then you SHOULD NOT use the `Resent` properties of the `MimeMessage`.