# How to forward an e-mail using the SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

I'm doing a WebForm where the user can forward a selected e-mail.
This is the method I'm using:

```
public bool SendEmail()
        {
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("host");

            try
            {
                smtpServer.Port = port;
                smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                smtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
                msg.From = new MailAddress("address");
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Subject = "FW: " + txtSubject.Text;
                msg.Body = txtBody.Value;

                //Sending email
                smtpServer.Send(msg);
                smtpServer.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

It's working just fine, but the thing is that **this is basically copying the e-mail and sending to the address informed by the user**. Is there a way to just **forward the message**, instead of **copy and send a new one**, using SmtpClient?

Comment: Is this useful? https://www.limilabs.com/blog/forward-email

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.  Where is the duplication happening?

Comment: SMTP is only for sending emails.  You would need to connect to an application that reads an email account and then forward.

Comment: @jdweng ouch, that's sad. Thank you for the comment, man.

Comment: @WiseGuy Actually there's no duplication. The thing is that I get the message selected by the user, copy the subject and body contents from it and send it to the address informed by the user. It's like a "fake forward", you know? Because I'm sending a new e-mail with the same contents of the other, not actually forwarding the original one.

Comment: @MuzafferGalata thanks for the reply man. I think I'll have to change the way I'm doing to something like this you've sent. I think I'll look for some library on GitHub to do this.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414995/forward-email-using-mailkit-c/29447087#29447087